# Vagrant-Ansible/Bash: Verify that a multiquoted block of code exists in file

Tags: bash, vagrant, ansible

How could it be verified that the following block of code exists in `.bashrc` and -if not- append it?

```
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}
```

Comment: It would be really easy using AWK.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thank you for the hint, I would certainly like to discover the simplicity of awk. Currently, I am struggling even to imagine it.

Comment: I feel a little guilty now for having said that.  I'll give you the code but I fear you won't like it.  Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the AWK solution but I must admit it is not “really easy”.  Basically, we are building a finite automaton that recognizes the three lines.  The exit status is 0 if and only if the pattern was found.

```awk
BEGIN {
    state = 0;
}

/.*/ {
    if ($0 == "function parse_git_branch {") {
        state = 1;
    } else if ($0 == "  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e \"s/* \\(.*\\)/[\\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/\"") {
        if (state == 1) {
            state = 2;
        } else {
            state = 0;
        }
    } else if ($0 == "}") {
        if (state == 2) {
            state = 3;
            exit 0;
        } else {
            state = 0;
        }
    } else {
        state = 0;
    }
}

END {
    # The END rule is always entered, even if we exit via 'exit' so we need to
    # check the state again.
    if (state < 3) {
        exit 1;
    }
}
```

The biggest problem I see is that this will answer “no” even if the function is present but formatted a little different (but syntactically equivalent).  You could try to improve this by using a more forgiving regular expression pattern instead of string comparison.

I feel there must be a better solution than this.  Maybe using diff?

Comment: Thank you for this really `wow` effort. It is awkward for my case but this must be the way `art` springs out when everything seems to be blatant!

Comment: @rara_tiru Well, in addition, it actually had a bad bug.  I've updated my answer to fix it.